# Align numbers about python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

Kilograms   Pounds

```
1              2.2
3              6.6
…                …
197          433.4
199          437.8
```

l want to show like Align numbers  that the Kilograms of the s align  1  3   and Pounds s
align 2 6

code:

```
print("Kilograms   Pounds")

for i in range(1,199+1,2):
    kg = i * 202
    print(i,format(kg,">15.1f"))
```

what should l do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also format `i` using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print("Kilograms   Pounds")

for i in range(1,199+1,2):
    kg = i * 202
    print('{:<3} {:>15.1f}'.format(i, kg))
```